# NSMenu with views in a modal NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an issue with selectors not being performed for custom views inside an NSMenuItem when they are displayed from a button within a modal NSWindow.

This appears to be a reproducible issue and I've simplified the issue as much as I can.

Modal window is displayed via.

```
   [NSApp runModalForWindow:_modalWindow];
```

The modal window only has a button, and the button is attached to the following selector.

```
- (IBAction)modalButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSMenu* aMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"];

    NSMenuItem* aItemA = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    NSMenuItem* aItemB = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    NSMenuItem* aItemC = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];

    [aItemA setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"Item A" target:self action:@selector(menuButtonClicked:)]];
    [aItemB setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"Item B" target:self action:@selector(menuButtonClicked:)]];
    [aItemC setView:[NSButton buttonWithTitle:@"Item C" target:self action:@selector(menuButtonClicked:)]];

    [aMenu addItem:aItemA];
    [aMenu addItem:aItemB];
    [aMenu addItem:aItemC];

    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:aMenu withEvent:[NSApp currentEvent] forView:sender];
}
```

and the menu click event with a breakpoint:

```
- (void)menuButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", sender);
}
```

Clicking on the button will display a menu with 3 buttons, however nothing happens when you click any of those buttons. @(menuButtonClicked:) is never called. This is only an issue with modal windows but there's no obvious reason why.

Comment: Very strange. If you don't set a target (`target: nil`) the responder chain will work correctly to forward the message along, but for some reason it seems the target doesn't get called with the action.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh I noticed that too. Unfortunately, this is a simplified version - if you replaced NSButton with NSView with multiple controls, setting target to nil doesn't help. Seems like a very odd behaviour.

Comment: Is this view a full window or is this like a pop up modal ? and does this occur in both ios 13 and earlier versions

Comment: It is a popup modal, and it's on macOS not iOS. I probably should have made that more clear!

Comment: Not sure if this is gnna help , but i am working on IOS and following the release pop ups had a issue with rendering since they tweaked the full page view . So once the page goes fullview and viewDidLoad is not called as we though it did anymore . So i had to change the story board property to full page. Now im not sure if this has any usage for MacOS but might be worth taking alook

Comment: I Fixed something similar by going to the storyboard of that modal and changing the presentation to "Full Screen" from automatic in the attribute inspector of that certain controller

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documention https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514843-target?language=objc states:

> To ensure that a menu item’s target can receive commands while a modal
>   dialog is open, the target object should return YES in worksWhenModal.

And indeed if one adds:

```
- (BOOL)worksWhenModal {
    return YES;
}
```

then it works and your method menuButtonClicked gives out something like:

```
2019-10-03 22:47:27.892005+0200 MenuTest[12876:454071] <NSButton: 0x600003505760>
```

Comment: It seems that, in order to get this working, the target actions of the menu items must be defined in the `NSWindow` object, and not in the view controller.